# How can I fit the width of an Image on the screen along with zooming and panning in Android studio

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, panning

In my app, I have an activity that has only one image view showing a long vertical  image, I can zoom and pan the Image but my problem is when I open the activity the full length of the image is shown like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75r7b.png)

But what i really want is my image to fit the width of the screen and to go further down the image the user should scroll
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gond.png)

This java class contains code for zooming and panning:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
    Matrix matrix;
    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;
    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;
    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }
        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }
            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }
        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;
        if (saveScale == 1) {
            //Fit to screen.
            float scale;
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);
            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;
            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }

}`
```

This class shows the Image on the screen:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import static android.R.attr.button;

public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pg2);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
        setContentView(img);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what changes I need to make in my code to fit the width of the image on the screen rather than the length and still be able to zoom and pann the image.

Comment: setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); to fitxy  and in xml view width match parent and height wrapcontent

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected behaviour using the ScrollView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

<TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:contentDescription="Specs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/specs" >
</TouchImageView >
```

Inflate this layout in your activity and get the TouchImageView from that like this:

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
```

And override this method:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return image.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: after I made the code changes It only zooms from the left side of the screen and I am unable to pan across the image
Please tell me how I can zoom the Image from anywhere and pan across it too
Thanks

Comment: I am getting a run time error
the error is on this line: "TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);"
Android monitor error message reads "at com.example.android.multitouchpinchzoompan.MultiTouchActivity.<init>(MultiTouchActivity.java:12)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)"

I dont know whats wrong.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please post the activity code, so that we can identify the problem.

Comment: public class MultiTouchActivity extends Activity {

    TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    @ Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_touch);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return img.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
Thanks